# how to use the currently unused space on a virtual disk?

Tags: linux, partitioning, fdisk

**What we have?**

df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            967M     0  967M   0% /dev
tmpfs           200M  7.8M  192M   4% /run
/dev/xvda2       28G   26G  180M 100% /
tmpfs           999M     0  999M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           999M     0  999M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

---

fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/xvda2: 48 GiB, 51539607552 bytes, 100663296 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/xvda1: 1 GiB, 1073741824 bytes, 2097152 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

---

`ls /dev | grep xvda`

```
xvda1
xvda2
```

---

`lsblk`

```
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda1 202:1    0   1G  0 disk [SWAP]
xvda2 202:2    0  48G  0 disk /
```

---

`cat /proc/partitions`

```
major minor  #blocks  name

 202        2   50331648 xvda2
 202        1    1048576 xvda1
```

---

I don't undersand:

- Where is `/dev/xvda`?
- What happened with 20Gb on `/dev/xvda2`?
- How to use the currently unused 20Gb?

---

**UPD1**

cat /etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
devpts          /dev/pts        devpts  rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=620 0  0
/dev/xvda1 none swap sw 0 0
/dev/xvda2 / ext4 defaults 0 1
```

Comment: What filesystem are you using? ext2/3/4?

Comment: Please edit your question for clarity - are you asking how to use the currently unused ~20GB, or are you asking how to add further storage?

Comment: Can you share the output of "cat /etc/fstab"

Comment: @Gefolge, see `UPD1`

Comment: @Attie, i fix question title, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xvd*` is a "*Virtual Disk*"... probably backed by a file by the hypervisor. It looks like you're using Xen as the hypervisor.

From the output you've posted, we can see that you have a 48GB partition, with a filesystem that is only using the first 28GB.

Thus, you need to expand the *filesystem* to use the whole partition - they are two independent things.

If you're using ext2/3/4 then you can use the following, which can be performed while the filesystem is mounted / online. This will automatically extend the filesystem to the length of the underlying device.

```
resize2fs /dev/xvda2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a new hard disk as virtual and you can extend the filesystem with below commands:

```
physicaldisk=/dev/sdxx                            # Physical Disk Name
vgname=vg_root                                   # Volume Group Name
lvname=lv_root                                   # Logical Volume Name
dirname=/                                    # Mount path
pvcreate $physicaldisk
vgextend $vgname $physicaldisk
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/vg_vgname/lv_lvname
resize2fs /dev/vg_vgname/lv_lvname
```

If you extend a filesystem you should a create physcial volume from a new hard disk firstly and then you should extend the volume group that realted the filesystem.

After extending of VG, you can extend Logical Volume with this new space. Because there are new space in VG for LV can extend.

And fianlly you must resize the filesystem with suitable command by your filesystem. (xfs_grows or resize2fs)

Comment: There is not a single mention of LVM in the question... `/` is mounted on `/dev/xvda2`.

Comment: Sorry, yes you're right @Attie. This answer is for LVM but logic is general disk logic.

Comment: @Gefolge, thx for answer. I'm sure it will come in handy.